# Show that $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that every Sylow subgroup of $G$ is normal and abelian.Show that $G$ is abelian.

Let $x,y\in G$ .

Case 1:If $x,y$ are in the same Sylow subgroup and as it is given  to be abelian so $xy=yx$.

Case 2:If $x,y$ are not in the same Sylow subgroup, so suppose that $x$ is in a Sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$ say $P$ and $y$ is in a Sylow $q$ subgroup of $G$,say $Q$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes.

Now $P,Q$ are normal and hence $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in P\cap Q=\{1\}\implies xy=yx$.

Thus $G$ is abelian.

Is the proof correct?Please suggest required edits.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Good job!

Comment: Very nice proof! You could also argue that under the given conditions $\;G\;$ is the direct product of tis Sylow subgroups.

Comment: You are missing case 3: at least one of $x$ and $y$ is not contained in a Sylow subgroup (not hard to fix since $G$ is generated by its Sylow subgroup, but definitely important).

Answer (score 1):

The proof requires a slight fix, because you appear to assume that if you take an element of $G$, it must be in one of the Sylow subgroups. The cyclic group of order $6$ show that this is not the case, unless $G$ is a $p$-group itself.

There are several ways of doing this correctly.

You may first use the fact that for a fixed prime $p$, the Sylow $p$-subgroups form a single conjugacy class. So in your case for each $p$ there is a single Sylow $p$-subgroup $S_{p}$.

Then use the elementary fact that every element of $G$ can be written as a product of elements of prime-power order.

Now you argue like this. Let $x, y \in G$. You know that $x = x_{1} x_{2} \dots x_{n}$ and $y = y_{1} y_{2} \dots y_{n}$, with $x_{i}, y_{i} \in S_{p_{i}}$. You have already proved that the $x_{i}, y_{i}$ commute, so you are done.

If you know direct products, you are really proving that $G$ is the product of the $S_{p}$.